# Using Ganglia on EC2

Tags: monitoring, amazon-ec2, ganglia

In Amazon EC2 I have a setup of proxies and 1 monitor (MON). I've installed gmond in the proxies and gmetad in MON. My data source for gmetad.conf in MON look like this:

```
data_source "proxies"  proxy1:8654 proxy2:8654 proxy3:8654
```

In the proxies's gmond.conf I have:

```
tcp_accept_channel {
  port = 8654
}
```

Everything is working fine, when I telnet from MON to the proxies I get the XML with the right data. The problem is that the web frontend only shows one source from cluster "proxies", indeed it shows the first source I put on the list, in this case proxy1. If I change the order:

```
data_source "proxies"  proxy2:8654 proxy3:8654 proxy1:8654
```

It only shows data from proxy2.

I've installed other monitoring systems in Ganglia using TCP or UDP, even through ssh tunnels but is the first time I see this behaviour. I'm not using multicast because (as far as I know) Amazon doesn't support on their network. Why is Ganglia-Web only showing one data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer reading this [README file](http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/HPC/basement/ganglia/README). The data_source directive is not working as I thought:

```
data_source "proxies"  proxy1:8654 proxy2:8654 proxy3:8654
```

This line is not going to pull data from the three sources, it pulls data from the first source and the others act as redundant sources. What I need to do is send all the data from the proxies to a gmond hub and then to the gmetad server.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Ganglia without multicast](https://serverfault.com/questions/22269/ganglia-without-multicast)

Comment: Thanks, it's what I was trying to do but my mistake was in the data_source line.

Answer (score 0):

See also:

https://github.com/ganglia/monitor-core/tree/feature/cloud

I installed it today and got it working on EC2 which doesn't allow multicast.